# Exclude a partition from a SQL window function?

Tags: sql, mariadb, window-functions

My goal is to calculate an average excluding the current partition. In the table below, I want to know how to generate the `avg_prod_rev_oth_cust` column: average product revenue for other customers. Can this be done with window functions?

```
cust  prod  rev  avg_prod_rev  avg_prod_rev_oth_cust
a       x    1           3.5         4.5
a       x    2           3.5         4.5
b       x    3           3.5         3.5
b       x    4           3.5         3.5
c       x    5           3.5         2.5
c       x    6           3.5         2.5
a       y    7           9.5        10.5
a       y    8           9.5        10.5
b       y    9           9.5         9.5
b       y   10           9.5         9.5
c       y   11           9.5         8.5
c       y   12           9.5         8.5
```

I am using MariaDB Columnstore. I believe Columnstore's window functions are syntactically similar to Amazon Redshift.

`avg_prod_rev_oth_cust` should be calculated as "the sum of this product's revenue excluding this customer / divided by the number of sales from other customers". For the first occurrence: (3+4+5+6)/4 .

Comment: how should `avg_prod_rev_oth_cust` be calculated?

Comment: As @vkp has mentioned, please explain in more detail how this calculation should work. Also, please provide DDL statements and example data in a usable form, e.g. as a SQL Fiddle (see http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: And it would also help us answer if you knew what database you are working with...

Comment: Some questions answered new version of question. DDL statements to follow.

Comment: Here is the SQL Fiddle which includes the answer below: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4d4ed/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `self join` and `avg` window function.

```
select distinct t1.*,avg(t2.rev) over(partition by t1.prod,t1.rev) as avg_prod_rev_oth_cust
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.prod=t2.prod 
where t1.cust<>t2.cust
```

Comment: Ah, well I didn't think the fact that I'm using MDB Columnstore would matter but apparently it does. MCS is somewhat limited and only allows `=` joins so I can't use the `<>` part. This looks like a good answer otherwise, thanks!

Comment: you can use that as a `where` condition instead.

Comment: Using where did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions (so, not really answering the question):

```
SELECT  cus,
        AVG(rev) AS AvgAll, 
        ( SELECT  AVG(rev) AS AvgOther
            FROM  ws_test
            WHERE  cus != t1.cus 
        ) AS AvgOther
    FROM  ws_test AS t1
    GROUP BY  cus;
```